# how to create table based on multiple table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

so i have multiple tables and i want to create new table based on all columns in those multiple tables. but if the column name are duplicate, then take just 1 column.

i tried to create the query like this :

```
CREATE TABLE schema_rr_dmt
  AS (SELECT al.*, rl.*, cs.*  FROM a_loans al INNER JOIN s_CUSTRLTNP rl 
ON al.id_nasabah = rl.id_nasabah INNER JOIN s_customer cs ON cs.id_nasabah = rl.enterprise_id);
```

but it turns error

```
[Error] Script lines: 8-10 -------------------------
 ORA-00957: duplicate column name
 Script line 9, statement line 2, column 22
```

how to just take only one column if there's same column name from multiple tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the only duplicate names are from the `join` keys, then `using` can solve your problem:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_rr_dmt AS
    SELECT *
    FROM a_loans al INNER JOIN
         s_CUSTRLTNP rl 
         USING (id_nasabah) INNER JOIN
         s_customer cs 
         ON id_nasabah = rl.enterprise_id;
```

However, this doesn't work if there are other duplicate column names.

Comment: based on my real case, there's 3 tables, first table is ```s_custrltnp``` with 8 column and one of the column is ```kd_cabang```, the next one is ```a_loans``` with 144 column and one of the column is ```kd_kolek``` the next one is ```s_customer``` with 63 column and have ```kd_kolek``` & ```kd_cabang``` inside of it, i want to take all of the column from those tables using ```inner join```, can i ```using``` those duplicate column?

Comment: @FahriDzaky . . . As this explain, this only works if the only duplicate columns are `join` keys in the `using` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You will have to enumerate each column that you want, rather than using the wildcard short cut. For example, if the tables A_LOANS and S_CUSTOMERS have a column called CUSTOMER_ID, then you will need explicitly list each of the columns from those two tables that you want...

```
CREATE TABLE schema_rr_dmt
  AS (SELECT al.col1, al.col2, al.CUSTOMER_ID, etc...
```

Incidently, you can include the duplicated column in your CTAS, but you would need to provide an alias for it to give it a unique name.

Comment: but what if for if there's a lot of columns in just one table? this way are manual way and is there any automatically way to solve this? because what i want to remove is just only column that have same name.

Comment: That’s how you have to do it. Now you can write a script against the data dictionary to generate the CTAS, but you have to generate the script to omit the duplicate columns, or disambiguate them

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `SELECT` where you have `al.*, rl.*, cs.*` Obviously you have same column names somewhere among your `*`. Hence you can't do this as minimum for 1 but may be 2 tables. What you need to fix this is to expand `*` list all fields like `al.col1, al.col2 as alCol2`. If only your table `rl` also has `col2` now you have no issues. But if your `rl` and `cs` have `col2`, minimum, one of them need to be aliased.

I suggest however, in such cases expand all columns

```
SELECT ... al.col2 as al_Col2, rl.col2 as rl_Col2, cs.col2 as cs_col2 ...`
```